# Crash in C2 ComplierThread1 guarantee(n != NULL) failed: No Node

Tags: java, smartfoxserver

Below is the thread dump taken after the crash. What will be the root cause for this issue?

The error log files contains the following:

> ```
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> #
> #  Internal Error (loopnode.hpp:622), pid=2530, tid=0x00007f6830f2f700
> #  guarantee(n != NULL) failed: No Node.
> #
> # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_222-b10) (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
> # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.222-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
> # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java
> ```
>
> again
> #
> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> #
>
> ```
> ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
>
> Current thread (0x00007f68900ce800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2549,
> ```
>
> stack(0x00007f6830e30000,0x00007f6830f30000)]
>
> ```
> Stack: [0x00007f6830e30000,0x00007f6830f30000],  sp=0x00007f6830f2adc0,  free space=1003k
> Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
> V  [libjvm.so+0x9f707d]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x15d
> V  [libjvm.so+0x4bfcee]  report_vm_error(char const*, int, char const*, char const*)+0x6e
> V  [libjvm.so+0x52e705]  PhaseIdealLoop::Dominators()+0x7b5
> V  [libjvm.so+0x76c85d]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_and_optimize(bool, bool)+0x44d
> V  [libjvm.so+0x46b269]  Compile::Optimize()+0xff9
> V  [libjvm.so+0x46d3ed]  Compile::Compile(ciEnv*, C2Compiler*, ciMethod*, int, bool, bool, bool)+0x109d
> V  [libjvm.so+0x3c8d68]  C2Compiler::compile_method(ciEnv*, ciMethod*, int)+0x1c8
> V  [libjvm.so+0x475b82]  CompileBroker::invoke_compiler_on_method(CompileTask*)+0x852
> V  [libjvm.so+0x476a28]  CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop()+0x4e8
> V  [libjvm.so+0x9a3268]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0xd8
> V  [libjvm.so+0x85ba92]  java_start(Thread*)+0xf2
> C  [libpthread.so.0+0x740b]  start_thread+0xdb
>
>
> Current CompileTask:
> C2:1095302843 16106 % !         com.org.app.className::methodName @ 534 (4676 bytes)
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What were you trying to do when the program crashed?

Comment: Current CompileTask:
C2:1095302843 16106 % !         com.org.app.className::methodName @ 534 (4676 bytes)

Comment: Current CompileTask:
C2:1095302843 16106 % !         com.org.app.className::methodName @ 534 (4676 bytes)

The line above is logged in the thread dump which I am thinking where the crash is happening. This method is handling many of java functionalities and more than 500+ lines of code written in this method has. I am unable to find the exact line where the error is happening.

Also if you know what exactly the log meaning is. (formatted in bold)

Current CompileTask:
C2:1095302843. **16106** % !         com.org.app.className::methodName **@ 534 (4676 bytes)**